# XAML throwing error - 'content' set more than once

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am trying to set my XAML up in order to work with some code that i have researched and added to my project. i want my XAML code to contain the following:

```
        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Sample twitter app" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="main page" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>                            
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <phone:WebBrowser Grid.Row="0" Margin="-6,3,0,1" Name="loginBrowserControl" Visibility="Collapsed"
                          Navigated="loginBrowserControl_Navigated" Navigating="loginBrowserControl_Navigating"/>

        <Grid x:Name="TweetPanel" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtUserName" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="26" FontFamily="Segoe WP Bold" Foreground="Red"/>
       </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

However, when i try to use it visual studio gives me the error 'the property 'content' is set more than once'. Anybody know what changes i need to make?

Thank you

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this posted code... please post your code where (your own surrounding XAML code) do you want to put this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a layout element wrapped around your code. Xaml page must have one root element. Heres an example using a Grid`

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"> ... your code above ... </Grid>
```

Comment: +1 for the requirement of a single parent root element, however it doesn't necessarily have to be restricted to only a `Grid` to be it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try put a stackpanel

```
 <StackPanel  Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
  <phone:WebBrowser  Margin="-6,3,0,1" Name="loginBrowserControl"   Visibility="Collapsed"
   Navigated="loginBrowserControl_Navigated" Navigating="loginBrowserControl_Navigating"/>
  <Grid x:Name="TweetPanel"  Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtUserName" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   FontSize="26" FontFamily="Segoe WP Bold" Foreground="Red"/>
   </Grid>
 </StackPanel>
```